# Calling protocol's mutating function generates "has no member 'functionName'" error

Tags: ios, swift, struct, swift-protocols

Here's my Protocol:

```
protocol RequestLocationAuthorizationPresenterProtocol {
    mutating func handleLoad(for view: RequestLocationAuthorizationViewProtocol)
    func handleGivePermissionAction()
}
```

Here's my protocol implementation:

```
struct RequestLocationAuthorizationPresenter: RequestLocationAuthorizationPresenterProtocol {
    private let interactor: RequestLocationAuthorizationInteractorProtocol
    private let router: RequestLocationAuthorizationRouterProtocol
    private weak var view: RequestLocationAuthorizationViewProtocol!

    init(with interactor: RequestLocationAuthorizationInteractorProtocol,
     router: RequestLocationAuthorizationRouterProtocol) {
        self.interactor = interactor
        self.router = router
    }

    mutating func handleLoad(for view: RequestLocationAuthorizationViewProtocol) {
        self.view = view
    }

    func handleGivePermissionAction() {
        self.interactor.requestAuthorization { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                self.router.goToWeatherView()
            case .error:
                self.view.presentAlert(with: "Error", message: "The app needs your location in order to work.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the function 'handleLoad' on my View class, it compiles perfectly. But, when I call it from a mock struct it gives me this error: *"Value of type 'RequestLocationAuthorizationPresenterProtocol?' has no member 'handleLoad'"*

Here's my view class:

```
class RequestLocationAuthorizationView: UIViewController {
    private let presenter: RequestLocationAuthorizationPresenterProtocol

    init(with presenter: RequestLocationAuthorizationPresenterProtocol) {
        self.presenter = presenter
        super.init(nibName: "RequestLocationAuthorizationView", bundle: .main)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func presentAlert(with title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func givePermissionButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.presenter.handleGivePermissionAction()
    }
}
```

And here's my mock struct:

```
class RequestLocationAuthorizationViewMock: RequestLocationAuthorizationViewProtocol {
    private let expectation: XCTestExpectation!
    private let expectedTitle: String!
    private let expectedMessage: String!
    private let presenter: RequestLocationAuthorizationPresenterProtocol!

    init(with expectation: XCTestExpectation? = nil,
         expectedTitle: String? = nil,
         expectedMessage: String? = nil,
         presenter: RequestLocationAuthorizationPresenterProtocol? = nil) {
        self.expectation = expectation
        self.expectedTitle = expectedTitle
        self.expectedMessage = expectedMessage
        self.presenter = presenter
    }

    func callPresenterHandleLoad() {
        self.presenter.handleLoad(for: self)
    }

    func callPresenterHandleGivePermissionAction() {
        self.presenter.handleGivePermissionAction()
    }

    func presentAlert(with title: String, message: String) {
        if title == self.expectedTitle && message == self.expectedMessage {
            self.expectation.fulfill()
        }
    }
}
```

When I change my implementation to be a class instead of a struct and remove the *mutating* word, it also works perfectly. I've tried to look for similar errors, but I had no luck. I'm on Xcode 10.1 and using Swift Compiler 4.2.

Any thoughts about this issue are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking more closely to the issue, I realize that I'm trying to call a mutating function a constant value (let) and that's why it was not working. The problem here was the compiler giving me a non-sense error. I changed my property from let to var and now it works.

Comment: There is no reason why `presenter` should not be a constant. The real problem is that you have not made it a `class`.

Comment: Well, I don't want it to be a class. I should't be forced to use a class just because.

Comment: Nobody is forcing you but there are differences between structs and classes. A struct cannot be used as a delegate. You will have big problems to use it as an output for router/interactor/presenter.

Answer (score 1):

`presenter` is an optional (even an implicit unwrapped optional is an optional), you have to add a question mark for optional chaining

```
func callPresenterHandleLoad() {
    self.presenter?.handleLoad(for: self)
}
```

But the error is misleading, now you get the real error

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'presenter' is a 'let' constant

so you have to declare presenter as `var`iable and – highly recommended – as regular optional

```
private var presenter: RequestLocationAuthorizationPresenterProtocol?
```

Comment: The presenter is declared as RequestLocationAuthorizationPresenterProtocol!, it's already being forced unwrapped.

Comment: Yes, but adding the question mark reveals the **real** error. See the updated answer. Moreover it prevents the code from crashing if `presenter` is not set. By the way `presenter` should be a regular optional (`?`) anyway.

Comment: Usually I would use '?' instead of '!', but since is a mock class, it's ok if it crashes. About the question mark revealing the error, it's true and I didn't know that and after you comment here I was able to see the real error. I truly believe the compiler should let me know the real error regarding being or not forced unwrapped. But, anyway, thank you for your help, I wouldn't be able to find the issue without your comment.

Comment: Actually, the presenter should be a `class` protocol. Components of a VIPER module are connected using references.